# Pseudoinverse of Gaussian matrix converges to its transpose

Tags: probability, matrices, matrix-calculus, random-matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $X$ be an $n\times m$ matrix with iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ entries.
I would like to show that
$$X^T\left(XX^T\right)^{-1}\rightarrow X^T$$
as $m\rightarrow \infty$, and $n$ is held fixed (and small).
Showing that $XX^T\rightarrow I$ is easy, one can apply the strong law of large number per entry ($n^2$ entries, where $n$ is fixed).
But since $X$ is not independent of $XX^T$, and the dimension of $X$ grows with $n$, I have difficulty showing the next step.

Comment: What type of convergence do you have in mind, specifically what does $M\rightarrow M^*$ (for $m\rightarrow\infty$) mean for a sequence (in $m$) of random matrices $M,M^*\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$?

Comment: @Matija I need convergence in probability but I think that it actually converges almost surely

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the proof of $XX^T\rightarrow I$, formalize the claim, and your ideas so far? Also, notice that as opposed to $XX^T\rightarrow I\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, the row dimension in your claim is diverging, which raises the question what underlying metric you consider.

Comment: @Matija I've edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I still don't understand the claim. I'm pretty sure you're looking at normed spaces, so $M\rightarrow M^*$ is equivalent to $\|M-M^*\|\rightarrow 0$ for some norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. But which norm do you have in mind? Especially for matrices there's plenty options, which aren't equivalent here, so I still fail to understand what the limit means.

Comment: The sizes of your matrices are not constant. What do you mean by convergence of a sequence of random variables when these random variables do not live in the same sample space?

Comment: @user1551 curious, what motivated this question? I came across similar question in linear estimation when trying to understand why gradient descent (which uses transpose of batch) performs almost as well as Newton (which uses pseudo-inverse)

Comment: Wouldn't it rather converge to $\frac{1}{m} X^{\top}$ instead of $X^{\top}$ ? Since $\frac{1}{m}X X^{\top}$ will be roughly $I_{n\times n}$ for large $m$, right ? (similarly to how the empirical covariance matrix of random iid samples approaches the true covariance matrix for large number of samples)